# How to code sign hidden files?

Tags: mac, code-signing

I have a hidden dylib file that is preventing notarization. The LogFileURL indicates the file is not signed and does not have a valid time stamp.

I tried to sign the file separately using the path to the dylib:

```
--force --verify --verbose --sign "PFish (MyID)" 
/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_App.app/Contents/Resources/sklearn/dylibs/libomp.dylib
```

which led to a "file not found error, not surprisingly, since the file is hidden.

When I enter

```
codesign --verify --verbose /Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_App.app
```

I'm informed

```
/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_App.app: valid on disk
```

which I also find not surprising.

Is there a way to codesign a hidden file?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden"?

Comment: The files are located within sklearn but are not shown unless I click on the sklearn folder and type command-shift-period.

Comment: Is it hidden with the `hidden` file flag, or something else? The `hidden` flag shouldn't cause a "file not found" error.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?